# Open a date picker from inside a v-select VUE

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js, computed-properties

I have a v-select with four items to choose different dates. The last item in the select is for choosing a manual date and then I want a menu/dialog to pop open with a date picker. But I can't get that to work...

```
    <v-select
        v-model="dates"
        :items="items"
        clearable
        hide-details
        :label="$tc('Dates')"
    >
        <v-menu
            v-model="showDatePicker"
            :close-on-content-click="false"
        >
            <template #item="{ item, on, attrs }"
                ><v-list-item v-attrs="attrs" v-on="on">{{ item.text }}</v-list-item>
            </template>
            <v-date-picker v-model="dates" @input="showDatepicker = false" />
        </v-menu>
    </v-select>
```

I've tried many different things but this is the latest one. Anyone that knows how to solve this? :)

Comment: Can you please create a plunker and share So that it will easy to find the root cause ?

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use v-select component.
With a watcher on the selected value, you can use v-if for the date picker with a boolean value that changes to true when you pick the selected value to open the date picker.
Else the value will be false and the date picker will get v-if="false"

Comment: Assuming that you are not misusing an answer post for asking a clarification question, please elaborate the solution you proposed. Ideally [edit] and try for [answer].